# Nested controller actions testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

In `routes.rb` i have:

```
resources :themes do
  resources :messages
end
```

In `messages_controller_test.rb` i have:

```
  setup do
    @theme = themes(:one)
    @message = messages(:one)
  end

  test "should create message" do
    assert_difference('Message.count') do
        post :create, message: { title: "Title", body: "Some body", theme_id: @theme.id }
    end

    assert_redirected_to theme_path(@theme)
  end
```

And i'm getting the error: `Couldn't find Theme without an ID`

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With nested resources, the create route looks like this:

```
/themes/:theme_id/messages
```

so you need to pass these params:

```
test "should create message" do
  assert_difference('Message.count') do
      post :create, {theme_id: @theme.id, message: { title: "Title", body: "Some body", theme_id: @theme.id }}
  end

  assert_redirected_to theme_path(@theme)
end
```

And actually in your controller action you can handle that :theme_id param in order not to pass it anymore in params[:message]

Comment: Awesome! That works for me! Now i have troubles with testing update action. What i try: `put :update, theme_id: @theme.id, id: @message.id, message: { title: "Title", body: "Some body", theme_id: @theme.id }`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Couldn't find Message with id=980190962 [WHERE `messages`.`theme_id` = 980190962]

Comment: mm is 980190962 a correct id of the message? does such message really exist in db?

Comment: Fixed that error with putting `id` and `theme_id` to fixtures manually. Is it correct?

Comment: All ids before were autogenerated. So now problem has gone away. Thanks for ur help :)